# VBA to dynamically resize table when data is added on protected sheet

Tags: excel, vba, dynamic, passwords, excel-tables

please can you help with VBA code to automatically resize my table once data is added to a protected sheet? When the sheet is unlocked and I add data the table automatically resizes but when it's locked it does't resize to include any data added.

I currently have this and it inserts 1 row only, I need it to resize the table to fit the number of rows where data is added (it could be 10 rows or 100):

```
Sub ExtendTable()
    ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="XXXX"
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("PortfolioTracker").ListRows.Add.Range.Locked = False
    ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="XXXX"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

How you will add data to the protected sheet? If you can add data to the protected sheet, then you can create a dynamic name range with `=offset()` formula.
Else if you are strick with VBA then you have to write the code, then you need to write the code under SheetChange event.

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)

' Code will be here

End Sub
```

Comment: Only certain cells are protected. It's basically a policy renewal list - we monitor the performance of the renewals - if they renew or cancel etc. The lists are generated every 3 months for the next set of renewals up and coming so they are able to add data.

Comment: I've got this far, it extends the table rows to whatever data is added but I can't get it to extend columns in case they decide they want to track additional information:

```
Sub ExtendTableRows()

   ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="X"

Dim tbl As ListObject

Set tbl = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("PortfolioTracker")
With tbl.Range
    tbl.Resize .Resize(.CurrentRegion.Rows.Count)
    
End With
 ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="X", AllowSorting:=True, AllowFiltering:=True, AllowUsingPivotTables:=True, DrawingObjects:=True, Scenarios:=False, AllowDeletingRows:=True

End Sub
```